# Error when trying to run steambot on vps debian System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Array.Empty'

Tags: mono, monodevelop, steam, steambot

I have built the solution using monodevelop on windows, then transferred the files to my vps using Filezilla. It works fine on windows. But when i try to run steambot using mono steambot.exe i get the errors:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Array.Empty'.
  at SteamBot.Program.BotManagerMode () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at SteamBot.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Array.Empty'.
  at SteamBot.Program.BotManagerMode () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at SteamBot.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
mattimat@mattimat-ubuntu:~/steambot/SteamBot-master/Bin/Release$ mono SteamBot.exe
Missing method System.Array::Empty<[1]>() in assembly /usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll, referenced in assembly /home/mattimat/steambot/SteamBot-master/Bin/Release/SteamBot.exe

Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Array.Empty'.
  at SteamBot.Program.BotManagerMode () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at SteamBot.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Array.Empty'.
  at SteamBot.Program.BotManagerMode () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at SteamBot.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
mattimat@mattimat-ubuntu:~/steambot/SteamBot-master/Bin/Release$
```

Mono version:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-8+deb7u1)
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc, Xamarin, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  x86
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
```

Again, works fine on windows. VPS is Debian 7.11 x32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public static T[] System.Array.Empty<T>()` was added in **.Net 4.6** and thus your older version of Mono would be running .Net 4.5 and the error would be expected.

Either update your version of Mono to 4.8+ or removed the usage of `Array.Empty` and compile against the .Net 4.5 framework.

re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906179(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you sooo much!! This was driving me nuts. Updating mono to 4.8+ fixed this issue for me.